# loose dependency

Tags: .net

scenario:

3 projects/assemblies:

assm1.class1

assm2.class2 -> depend on assm1.class1

assm3.class3 -> depend on assm2.class2

in VS, assm3.class3 will need to reference assm1.class1 as well, becos assm2 depend on it.

is there a way I can make it (assm)3 only depend 2 without 1?

so that in future when I decided to change 2, to use/depend on new/diff thing like assm4.class4, I can just recompile assm2 without the need to recompile assm3.

Answer (score 1):

yes, I could implement [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) approach and define an interface in assm2 which would be implemented in assm1 by class1.

Comment: say, if i use Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 . Unity is the stuff I should look into, right?

Comment: @Kelmen yes, Unity is a great tool you may use to do DI.